# RecyclerView , kotlin, click response delay

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, interface

Peace
i have made simple recyclerview, with interface clickListener
consisting of 4 items showing toast on click.
It works fine if i single click per second,
but if i Rapidly click on different items ( 2 or 3 times in 1 seconds )
it still shows the toast each second,
not rapidly changing the toast

data class code:

```
    package com.elsersy.rv5

data class Items (var textt:String) {
}
```

adapter code

```
package com.elsersy.rv5

import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.DiffUtil
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView

class MyAdapter(private var stringList:ArrayList<Items>,private val listener:MyOnClickListener):
    RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.MyViewHolder>() {
    inner class MyViewHolder(itemView:View):RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        var text:TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView)

        init {
            itemView.setOnClickListener {
                val position = absoluteAdapterPosition
                if (position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION)
                {
                    listener.onItemClick(position)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): MyViewHolder {
        val itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.row_item,parent,false)
        return MyViewHolder(itemView)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val currentItem = stringList[position]
        holder.text.text = currentItem.textt
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return stringList.size
    }
    interface MyOnClickListener{
        fun onItemClick(position: Int)
    }
    fun setData(newItemList:ArrayList<Items>){
        val diffUtil = MyDiffUtil(stringList,newItemList)
        val diffResults = DiffUtil.calculateDiff(diffUtil)
        stringList = newItemList
        diffResults.dispatchUpdatesTo(this)
    }
}
```

ActivityMainCode

```
    package com.elsersy.rv5

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import com.elsersy.rv5.databinding.ActivityMainBinding

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(),MyAdapter.MyOnClickListener {
    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding
    private lateinit var stringList:ArrayList<Items>

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        val view = binding.root
        setContentView(view)

        binding.recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
        stringList = arrayListOf<Items>()
        getStrings()
        binding.recyclerView.adapter=MyAdapter(stringList,this)
    }

    private fun getStrings() {
        for (a in 0..4){
            var string_Array = resources.getStringArray(R.array.string_array)
            stringList.add(Items(string_Array[a]))
        }
    }

    override fun onItemClick(position: Int) {
        Toast.makeText(this,"$position is clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly  you are planning to do with toasts ?

Comment: just to confirm that clicklistener is working correctly, but even if i make the click increase an integer by one, if i click many times, it increases one per second

Answer (score 0):

If you want to cancel the previous toast before showing a new one, assign it as a member variable and cancel it before showing the new one:

```
private var toast : Toast? = null
        ..
override fun onItemClick(position: Int) {
     toast?.cancel()
     toast = Toast.makeText(this,"$position is clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
     toast?.show()
}
```

Comment: the problem is not the toast it self.... even if i make the click increase an integer by one, if i click many times, it increases one per second... i want to know why this 1 second interval is present

Comment: If you are testing this behaviour with toasts, toast is a problem, because toasts don't replace previous automatically. (It would be the same problem if you'd show toasts by clicking rapidly on a regular button) Did you test with logs instead? I mean write the position to logs instead of showing a toast.

Comment: i tested it with int++ .. onItemClick( count++) .. multiple clicks increases 1 per second,

Comment: ok i will try and tell u. thanks for replying

Comment: @MuhammadElsersy  I mean replace the toast with this: Log.d("MainActivity", "$position is clicked") and observe logs. Or use the solution I proposed for cancelling previous toasts.